# Calculate the Laplacian of Kuramoto model

Tags: matrices, graph-theory, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-dynamics, graph-laplacian

I am trying to calculate the Laplacian of the Kuramoto model which describes the phase dynamics of a set of $N$ phase oscillators $i$ with natural frequencies $\omega_i$
$$ \dot{\theta}_i = \omega_i + \frac{K}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N \sin(\theta_j - \theta_i). $$
The idea of the Laplacian as I understand it is that it would satisfy $\dot{\theta} = -L \theta$ where $\theta$ is a vector. I found a solution in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0504419.pdf) where the equation is first rewritten using order parameters of $Re^{i\psi} = \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^{N}e^{i \theta_j}$ in the usual way
$$ \dot{\theta}_i = \omega_i - \frac{K}{N} R \sin(\theta_i - \psi). $$
(Actually it seems to me that they should replace $\frac{K}{N}$ with just $K$). From here they say that the Laplacian is given by $L = B B^T$ where $B$ is the incidence matrix, and they then claim that the incidence matrix satisfies
$$ \dot{\theta} = \omega - \frac{K}{N} B \sin(B^T \theta) $$
where $\theta$ and $\omega$ are vectors. I see the analogy between these last two equations, but I don't understand at all how they have derived the incidence matrix or even what the incidence matrix would look like if it were written out in full. Does anyone have any ideas? Are there maybe also other ways to derive the Laplacian?

Comment: The paper states that $B$ is the incidence matrix of a generalized network. So it doesn't **derive** $B$, instead it is a known parameter of the network being analyzed.

Comment: Ah now I understand this a bit better. So the coordinate transformation with the order parameters is not necessary to derive B. As I now understand it the original equation $\dot{\theta}_i = \omega_i - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{j=1}^N \sin(\theta_i - \theta_j)$ can be rewritten using $B$ where $B$ has a column for each connection and in the case of all to all coupling (undirected) there would be a 1 and a -1 in each column with the location of the -1 just being a question of definition.

Comment: But now I'm a bit confused, because it seems to me that the Laplacian $L = B B^T$ wouldn't satisfy the equation $\dot{\theta} = -L \theta$. What have I misunderstood?

Comment: So I guess the equation $\dot{\theta} = -L \theta$ is satisfied, but only for something similar to the linearised Kuramoto model $\dot{\theta}_i = \sum_{j=1}^N (\theta_j - \theta_i)$.